GoLang - looping through array of structs - can I map?
I'm new to GoLang, coming from Node. A little late to the (definitely not functional) game and need some help understanding approaches, and perhaps just understanding...
I want to omit an item from a bunch of structs in an array.
lo.Map(twelveShuffledQuestions, func(q StaticQuestion) {
        return &StaticQuestionMinusCorrectAnswer{
            QuestionId:       q.QuestionId,
            QuestionType:     q.QuestionType,
            QuestionText:     q.QuestionText,
            PotentialAnswers: q.PotentialAnswers,
            Image:            q.Image,
        }
    })

All this is basically doing is showing a pattern how I would go about it in node (with the help of lo) - and no, this isn't compiling as it cant infer the type args.
In terms of the data structure here, twelveShuffledQuestions is JSON backed, meaning it was imported and then marshalled:
jsonFile, err := os.Open("questions.json")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer jsonFile.Close()
byteValue, _ := io.ReadAll(jsonFile)
localQuestionsToCheckAgainst := []StaticQuestion{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &localQuestionsToCheckAgainst)

My question is how do I achieve this mapping of fields I want from the structs in the array?

If you're learning the language, I'd suggest to not use the lo package. The idiomatic way to write this code is to iterate over the loop yourself, building the result slice yourself (for example, as in the answer by Eaton Scribner). This may change with the next go release which will include iterators, but that's the best way right now. Go isn't Node, and the go idiom is to write simple things yourself rather than use dependencies.

Noted, many thanks

Loop over the original questions.  Create a question without answer and append to the result.
byteValue, err := os.ReadFile("questions.json")
if err != nil { panic(err) }
var localQuestionsToCheckAgainst []*StaticQuestion
json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &localQuestionsToCheckAgainst)
var result []*StaticQuestionMinusCorrectAnswer
for _, q := range localQuestionsToCheckAgainst {
    result = append(result, &StaticQuestionMinusCorrectAnswer{
        QuestionId:       q.QuestionId,
        QuestionType:     q.QuestionType,
        QuestionText:     q.QuestionText,
        PotentialAnswers: q.PotentialAnswers,
        Image:             q.Image,
    })
}

Here's how to use the lo package:
byteValue, err := os.ReadFile("questions.json")
if err != nil { panic(err) }
var localQuestionsToCheckAgainst []*StaticQuestion
json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &localQuestionsToCheckAgainst)
result := lo.Map(localQuestionsToCheckAgainst, func(q *StaticQuestion, i int) *StaticQuestionMinusCorrectAnswer {
    return &StaticQuestionMinusCorrectAnswer{
        QuestionId:       q.QuestionId,
        QuestionType:     q.QuestionType,
        QuestionText:     q.QuestionText,
        PotentialAnswers: q.PotentialAnswers,
        Image:            q.Image,
    }
})

A for loop with range clause (the first snippet in this answer) is the idiomatic way to write the code.  The upcoming range function feature makes for loops the preferred way to write most iteration code.
